Installation of WMIC is encountering issues due to the absence of the GMP library
hope you guys are having a great day/night!
Well as a beginner in python, i have been trying to setup some softwares that help me do what i want using the help of ChatGPT (I'm guilty). One of the software features that i wanted is Search for Hard Disks and change their serials without me doing it manually.
In the process of that i have succeded in Importing Serials and "Changing them automatically".
But the problem is the program is saying that it's not having enough permissions to do so!
So i went to chatGPT and uploaded the code, and edited the code for me to Include "WMIC".
While installing "WMIC" i had errors saying that i need "GMP".
  Building wheel for pycrypto (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [28 lines of output]
      warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
      winrand.c
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(31): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'intmax_t'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(32): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'rem'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(32): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(33): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(35): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'imaxdiv_t'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(35): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(45): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '_Number'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Number'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(50): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '_Numerator'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Numerator'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2059: syntax error: ','
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(53): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(55): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(61): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(68): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(74): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(81): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(87): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(94): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(100): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycrypto
  Running setup.py clean for pycrypto
  Building wheel for dsinternals (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for dsinternals: filename=dsinternals-1.2.4-py3-none-any.whl size=208328 sha256=e3f4385e71e15f453153b1290e019bea04e125c808a117fee60adee5826a9c2d
  Stored in directory: c:\users\win 10\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\03\55\a4\5a698429d511a8e35d5ce4a9d55c0ea11aff182ec9013a3505
Successfully built wmic impacket dsinternals
Failed to build pycrypto
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycrypto, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

After that i downloaded GMP from Github (https://github.com/vhnatyk/gmp-release/blob/master/gmp_x86_win.zip ), added it to %PATH% variable and restarted my PC.
echo path details
And the surprise, even doing so! It's not working!!
I tried using GMP from Github, and added to the %PATH% and it is not working just yet!
